# Draw Polygon on GoogleMap API V2

Tags: android

I have a map view in a fragment which shows google map nicely I want to draw the polygon on the map.I searched google but not getting the good tutorial.So anybody has any idea or any good tutorial.
Please  Share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a triangle in the Gulf of Guinea
 Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
 .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(0, 0))
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

reference: [Google Maps Android API v2 - Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon)

Comment: Thanks for replying...but I want the user draw the polygon on any latlng position not with that specified one.

Comment: you have to override onTouchEvent on the Google map overlay. you can find an example here: http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-google-maps-android

Comment: I have implemented OnMapClickListener and OnMapLongClickListener it shows line on the touch but i want the line on the drag event and not getting that...